# SQL Server Query for Team/Individual Score Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking to build a query to give me the score for individual managers and the employees underneath them (if applicable).

```
MGR_ID  EMP_ID  QUESTION  SCORE   TYPE
DEF456  YEA667    1       10      INDIVIDUAL
AND987  ABC123    4       10      INDIVIDUAL
YEA667  BRD715    1       9       INDIVIDUAL
ABC123  DRE445    9       2       INDIVIDUAL
```

I am trying to work out a query that would return me all mgr_id and their individual scores (type = INDIVIDUAL) along with a team score (TYPE = TEAM) if they have a valid emp_id working for them.

I.E.: For MGR_ID DEF456 I am looking to get the following data

```
MGR_ID     QUESTION     SCORE     TYPE
DEF456     1            19        PRACTICE
DEF456     1            10        INDIVIDUAL
```

The score column should equal the combined total of the two score values.

Hope this all makes sense, I have been spinning wheels on coming up with a query for this for a couple hours and feel like I am falling further and further away from a solution.

Thanks in advance for all of your help

Comment: how are you arriving at `DEF456     1            19        PRACTICE` you need to add in your manager table. Can you include what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am taking the mgr_id (DEF456) the quetion number and then adding the score for the mgr_id and emp_id (10+9=19)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select MGR_ID,QUESTION,SUM(SCORE) as SCORE,TYPE
from TABLE_NAME
group by MGR_ID,QUESTION,TYPE
order by MGR_ID,QUESTION,TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it's not exactly what I am looking for. That query only gives me the score of the single mgr_id. I need the sum of the mgr_id answer along with them emp_id that is tied to them.